# How to remove a gain node?

Tags: javascript, audio, garbage-collection, web-audio-api

In the example below, the gain node is not removed from the audio context, at least according to the *Web Audio* debugger in Firefox 66.0.5 (64-bit) / Windows 10.

[image: Screenshot of web audio debugger]

*What needs to be done to eliminate the gain node?*

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script>
  var context = new window.AudioContext();
  var osc = context.createOscillator();
  var gain = context.createGain();

  osc.connect(gain);
  gain.connect(context.destination);
  osc.start();

  window.setTimeout(function () {
      osc.stop();
      osc.disconnect();
      gain.disconnect();
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying setting

```
gain = null;
```

Right now, you're still hanging on to the object reference ("gain" is a global variable).

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Note that `osc` is a global variable too, and it does get garbage collected. There are no references to `gain`.